Helm template: setting multiple key value pairs
I want to dynamically inject multiple key value pairs in the helm chart using --set-string. This is the end goal I am trying to achieve:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap1 
data:
  key1: "value1"
  key2: "Value2"

Where the following is dynamically injected:
  key1: "value1"
  key2: "value2"

So, if three key,value pairs are injected, it will render as:
  key1: "value1"
  key2: "value2"
  key3: "value3"

So far I have this in my template yaml file:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap1
data:
  {{- range $env_key, $env_value := .Values.env }}
  {{ $env_key }}: "{{ $env_value }}"
  {{- end }}

This works well when it picks up the default values of env from values.yaml file:
env:
  key1: "value1"
  key2: "Value2"

This is how it looks like:
bash-3.2$ helm template my-helmchart
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap1 
data:
  key1: "value1"
  key2: "Value2"
bash-3.2$ 

But I want to inject it using --set-string. This didn't work:
bash-3.2$ helm template workflow-helmchart --set-string env={key1:value1\,key2:value2}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap1 
data:
  0: "key1:value1"
  1: "key2:value2"
bash-3.2$ 

Any thoughts? What should be my helm template --set-string command to pass in the list of key,value pairs?

Can you use helm template -f with a secondary YAML or JSON values file, instead of trying to figure out the vagaries of the --set syntax?

According to the documentation of helm template command:

--set-string stringArray: set STRING values on the command line (can specify multiple or separate values with commas: key1=val1,key2=val2)

So instead of:
helm template workflow-helmchart --set-string env={key1:value1\,key2:value2}

Try:
helm template workflow-helmchart --set-string --set-string env.key1="value1",env.key2="value2"

Please note that using double quotes (env.key1="value1") can prevent issues if the values contain white-space or special characters.
